# Write CSV Data to hard disk progressively to reduce memory usage

Tags: python, csv, memory, memory-management

I've written a multithreaded web crawler that gathers data to be eventually written to a very large csv file. The only problem is, the program is using a tremendous amount of memory at the moment (had it at 15gb+ of memory, all of my computer's physical memory is being used). I'm not sure how python is managing the memory in the background but the program seems to be functional nonetheless, but I do get these pauses frequently which I think are to do with either python or the system doing some "memory magic" in the background. The only other thing it could be is CPU usage.

Anyway, I think it would be helpful to write the data to the hard disk progressively so to reduce the memory usage. I'm not doing any additional operations on the data, so I really don't need it in memory.

I was thinking I could do something like:

```
# out_queue is queue.Queue() object containing data to be written
def csv_writer(out_queue):

    with open(file, 'w+') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile,delimiter=',')
        while True:
            task = out_queue.get()
            writer.writerow(task)
            task.task_done()
```

But I'm not not sure how the `open` function works, reading the documentation it said that a file object is returned, but I'm not sure what that really means. So I suppose the main questions here are:

If I'm using a `with open` statement, is the open file held in memory? Reading the documentation didn't particularly help me.

I also read something about opening a file with buffering, would that be helpful in this instance?

If you have any other tips, for those of you out there who have dealt with these kind of issues, is there a better way to resolve it? Or should I just leave it to python to handle regardless?

Comment: Sorry may not have explained well, my memory problems are because I'm holding all the data scraped from the net in memory. Currently the program is structured to write all of the data to the file after all my scraper threads have exited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, using a file object as a context manager (through the `with` statement) does not cause it to hold all data in memory. All it does is ensure that the file object is closed when the context is exited. The file object *already* buffers writes, but the buffer holds a few kilobytes at most. The `csv.writer()` object writes data to the underlying file object immediately, no data is retained.

Your problem lies elsewhere, the code you've shown here will *not* hold on to gigabytes of memory. Use a memory profiler (such as [HeapPy](http://guppy-pe.sourceforge.net/#Heapy) or [`memory_profiler`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler)) to figure out what is causing your process to use so much memory.